# Redirect wordpress website to another site

Tags: php, database, wordpress, redirect

I moved my wordpress website with updraftpluse backup plugin to another domain and now when I open new domain website redircet to Previous domain.
what can I do for fix this problem?
please help m!

Answer (score 0):

Migration to a new domain is a different task from restoring a backup. Doing it correctly requires updating hyperlinks embedded in your site's content, as well as loading the site data onto the new server. It's quite difficult to update all the hyperlinks manually. But if you don't you get the results you mentioned in your question.

Updraft's paid version supports migration and automates the hyperlink update operations.   So does Duplicator's free version.